# Excel - Using one cell on a master sheet to populate multiple info on another tab

Tags: excel, populate

I am creating a workbook for a fishing tournament that has multiple tournaments the fisherman can sign up for.  I have a master sheet with all the information, including a cell for each tournament they can sign up for.  If there is an "X" in a cell I want to populate the First, Last, Phone to another page to create a registration page. One image is the master, if a lake has an X I want to populate the info in Image 2

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Comment: This a reasonably easy job in VBA to populate a form. I might suggest that you start there

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: Also, if those are real phone numbers, you should probably not show them.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're missing the link for Image 2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example showing you how to move data between sheets:

```
Sub PopulateNames()

Dim c As Range
With Sheets("Master")
    'Loop through all cells in column D looking for "X"
    For Each c In .Range("D2:D" & .Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        If c.Value = "X" Then
            'Copy the data from column A-C over to Tournament1 Sheet
            .Range("A" & c.Row & ":C" & c.Row).Copy Sheets("Tournament1").Range("A" & _
                Sheets("Tournament1").Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
        'Optionally resize columns so contents fit
        Sheets("Tournament1").Columns.AutoFit
    Next c
    'Loop through all cells in column E looking for "X"
    For Each c In .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
        If c.Value = "X" Then
            'Copy the data from column A-C over to Tournament2 Sheet
            .Range("A" & c.Row & ":C" & c.Row).Copy Sheets("Tournament2").Range("A" & _
                Sheets("Tournament2").Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
        'Optionally resize columns so contents fit
        Sheets("Tournament2").Columns.AutoFit
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

Note that this does not clear data from the sheets prior to moving them - it will append them to the end of the sheet by looking for the last row in column A.

Results:

[image: MasterSheet]

[image: Tournament1]

[image: Tournament2]